# Select specific checkbox based on index in React using onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

I have a list where I'm iterating though every item and it has a checkbox to select a particular list item. The problem I'm facing now is, when I select one item, it checks all the items in the list. How do I check only particular item that is selected?

Excerpt from my code

```
export default function App() {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
  const names = ["John", "Doe", "Jim"];
  const handleCheck = (event, index) => {
    console.log(event.target.checked);
    console.log(index);
    setChecked(event.target.checked);
    return event.target.checked;
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {names.map((values, index) => (
        <div>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            checked={checked}
            onChange={(event) => handleCheck(event, index)}
          />
          {values}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I created a working example using [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-wildflower-um3f0?file=/src/App.js). Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the `input` tag `checked` value with one state boolean variable.

Make `checked` state as an array and indicate it using `index` for input tag.

On `handleCheck()` method, update the corresponding index item of the state.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [allchecked, setAllchecked] = useState(false);
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState([false, false, false]);
  const names = ["John", "Doe", "Jim"];
  const handleCheck = (event, index) => {
    const _checked = [...checked];
    _checked[index] = event.target.checked;
    setChecked(_checked);
  };

  const selectAll = (event) => {
    setAllchecked(event.target.checked);
    const isChecked = event.target.checked;
    console.log(isChecked);
    setChecked([isChecked, isChecked, isChecked]);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="checkbox" checked={allchecked} onChange={selectAll} />
      Select All
      {names.map((values, index) => (
        <div>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            checked={checked[index]}
            onChange={(event) => handleCheck(event, index)}
          />
          {values}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This is great! With this approach, will I be able to mark all as `true` when select all button is clicked? 
`setChecked((checked) => checked.map((values) => !values));`
I did something like this which won't check the select All checkbox.

Comment: simply, just `setChecked([true, true, true])`

Comment: But the select All checkbox won't get checked :(
I updated my code in the sandbox link. Could you please take a look.

Comment: since "selectAll" is the another checkbox, you need to add another state for this.